# creating struct within struct

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm working on importing an old C windows driver project that was created in Visual c++ 6.0 into visual studio 2012. The way that the structs were defined are causing errors in vs2012.

```
typedef struct {
    LINK               Link;
    HANDLE             hFile;
    BYTE               handleType;
    OVERLAPPED         Overlapped;
    CRITICAL_SECTION   csIoCtrl;
} USB_HANDLE, *PUSB_HANDLE;

typedef struct {
    USB_HANDLE;        //error occurs here saying nothing was declared for USB_HANDLE
    LIST               PipeList;
    BOOL               bRemoved;
    CRITICAL_SECTION   csPipeList;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA *InterfaceData;
} USB_DEVICE, *PUSB_DEVICE;
```

The project then uses calls like
USB_DEVICE mydevice;
mydevice->hfile = handle;

Is this type of structure possible in vs2012?

(edit - though these do show as errors, visual studio 2012 did compile and successfully build a solution. I will be testing the driver to see if everything works properly soon.)

Errors:

[image: struct declaration error message]

[image: member error message]

A work around that I thought I could use was making the USB_DEVICE struct:

```
typedef struct {
    USB_HANDLE         USB_HANDLE;        
    LIST               PipeList;
    BOOL               bRemoved;
    CRITICAL_SECTION   csPipeList;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA *InterfaceData;
} USB_DEVICE, *PUSB_DEVICE;
```

Then I could make the rest of the calls:
mydevice->USB_HANDLE.hfile = handle;

Is this an equivalent statement?

Comment: You can fix this by giving a name to the USB_HANDLE in the USB_DEVICE.

Comment: We shouldn't have to ask what the error message says, as it should be in your first sentence: "I'm getting the following error message in VS2012: ...". Please enlighten us with this critical information.

Answer (score 1):

Define a macro to declare the `USB_HANDLE` and then use it in both.  Like,

```
#define HANDLE_BODY                \
   LINK               Link;        \
   HANDLE             hFile;       \
   BYTE               handleType;  \
   OVERLAPPED         Overlapped;  \
   CRITICAL_SECTION   csIoCtrl;

typedef struct {
   HANDLE_BODY
} USB_HANDLE, *PUSB_HANDLE;

typedef struct {
    HANDLE_BODY
    LIST               PipeList;
    BOOL               bRemoved;
    CRITICAL_SECTION   csPipeList;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA *InterfaceData;
} USB_DEVICE, *PUSB_DEVICE;
```

You can create a `union` if you also need that.  Otherwise, you may need some special non-standard compiler options.  For instance, many compiler support `transparent_union`, which would also solve your issue.  However, I don't think Visual C++ supports this.  But maybe someone more knowledgeable of these products can help.

Comment: You might also like to place a comment about the problem.  I wouldn't recommend this for new code, but it may allow you to work around the issue and at least get the system running with the new tool.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type USB_HANDLE in USB_DEVICE does not define any variable.

```
typedef struct {
    USB_HANDLE         handler;  // handler is missing?
    LIST               PipeList;
    BOOL               bRemoved;
    CRITICAL_SECTION   csPipeList;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA *InterfaceData;
} USB_DEVICE, *PUSB_DEVICE;
```